# parsing tiled json map into html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, tiled

I am trying to make a 2d top view javascript game and i want to make my map using program "tiled" i have made my map and have the exported json but dont know how to parse it into a canvas html tag and i dont know were to start here is my crazy game code

```
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
<script>
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function() {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/newbackground.png";
//hp box
var hpBoxReady = false;
var hpBoxImage = new Image();
hpBoxImage.onload = function() {
    hpBoxReady = true;
};
hpBoxImage.src = "images/hpbox.png";
// player image
var playerReady = false;
var playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.onload = function() {
    playerReady = true;
};
playerImage.src = "images/char.png";

// enemy image
var enemyReady = false;
var enemyImage = new Image();
enemyImage.onload = function() {
    enemyReady = true;
};
enemyImage.src = "images/enemy_idle01.png";

// Game objects
var hpBox = {
    restoreHealth: 34,
    x: 300,
    y: 300
}
var player = {
    stamina: 7,
    health: 100,
    sprintSpeed: 400,
    weakSpeed: 150,
    speed: 300 // movement in pixels per second
};
var enemy = {
    speed: 250,
    viewDistance: 40
};
var enemysCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a enemy
var reset = function() {
    player.x = canvas.width / 2;
    player.y = canvas.height / 2;

    // Throw the enemy somewhere on the screen randomly
    enemy.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    enemy.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};



//w is 87
//a is 65
//s is 83
//d is 68
// Update game objects
var update = function(modifier) {
    if (87 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        player.y -= player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (83 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        player.y += player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (65 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        player.x -= player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (68 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        player.x += player.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (
        player.x <= (0)) {
        player.health -= 1;
        console.log('health decreasing');
    }
}
if (
    player.y <= (0)) {

    player.health -= 1;
    console.log('health decreasing');
};

// Are they touching?
if (
    player.x <= (enemy.x + 32) &&
    enemy.x <= (player.x + 32) &&
    player.y <= (enemy.y + 32) &&
    enemy.y <= (player.y + 32)
) {
    ++enemysCaught;
    reset();
}

// Draw everything
var render = function() {
    if (bgReady) {
        context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
    if (hpBoxReady) {
        context.drawImage(hpBoxImage, hpBox.x, hpBox.y);
    }
    if (playerReady) {
        context.drawImage(playerImage, player.x, player.y);
    }

    if (enemyReady) {
        context.drawImage(enemyImage, enemy.x, enemy.y);
    }

    // Score
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    context.font = "24px Helvetica";
    context.textAlign = "left";
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillText("enemys killed: " + enemysCaught, canvas.width / 2, 32);
};

function dieEvent() {
    player.health = 100;
}

function updateHealth() {
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255 ,0 ,0)";
    context.textAlign = "right";
    context.fillText("Health: " + player.health, 1000, 32)

}

function isNearHPBox() {

    if (
        player.y <= (hpBox.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
        player.y >= (hpBox.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
        player.x <= (hpBox.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
        player.x >= (hpBox.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
        console.log("healing!");
        if (player.health <= 100) {
            hpBox.restoreHealth = player.health - 100;
            player.health += hpBox.restoreHealth;
        }

    }

}

function moveEnemy() {
    if (
        player.y <= (enemy.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
        player.y >= (enemy.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
        player.x <= (enemy.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
        player.x >= (enemy.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
        console.log("seen on enemys Y");
        var audio = new Audio('sounds/theWanderer_Scream.m4a');
        audio.play();
        if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
            enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
        }
        if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
            enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
        }
    }
}

function checkWallCollision() {
    if (player.y <= 0) {
        console.log("y")
        player.y += 64;
    }
    if (player.x <= 0) {
        console.log("x")
        player.x += 64;
    }
    if (enemy.y <= 0) {
        console.log("y")
        enemy.y += 64;
    }
    if (enemy.x <= 0) {
        console.log("x")
        enemy.x += 64;
    }
}

function reducedSpeed() {
    player.speed = player.weakSpeed;
}
// The main game loop
var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    update(delta / 1000);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    render();
    updateHealth();
    moveEnemy();
    if (player.health <= 20) {
        reducedSpeed();
    } else {
        player.speed = 300;
    }
    if (player.health <= 0) {
        dieEvent();
    }
    checkWallCollision();
    isNearHPBox();
    then = now;

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
</script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

i have tried all the tutorials but cant seem to get it to work so for now i just have a small little background image could sombody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit general. I recommand to enroll Udacity's [HTML5 Game Development](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs255/lessons/52473341/concepts/662559270923) course I think many part of your question should be answered after watching that course.

Comment: I have been watching this but I just can't figure it out and learn from them can you please help

Comment: I have watched that course too, It's so simple but it needs a bit tweaking and wrangling with java script.
You can use JSON.parse(textRetrivedViaXHR) to parse the json text that retrived from your server. If you have not any server on your system you can use XAMP or any other similar packages to run a server on your local machine and host your json and images.

If you didn't find this answer related, try more specify your question.